# Many autocreated migration files using Django in Docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Just got started with Docker last week. In my apps, am seeing so many auto created migration files even if I have ran the `docker-compose -f local.yml run django python manage.py makemigrations` once. In the log below, I just switched on my machine and saw about 30 migration files created in the past 15 minutes.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep  9 12:54 0053_auto_20170909_0954.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep  9 12:55 0054_auto_20170909_0955.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep  9 12:55 0055_auto_20170909_0955.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep  9 12:55 0056_auto_20170909_0955.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep  9 12:56 0057_auto_20170909_0956.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep  9 17:57 0058_auto_20170909_0958.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep  9 21:58 0059_auto_20170909_0958.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep  9 23:58 0060_auto_20170909_0959.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 00:58 0061_auto_20170909_0959.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:53 0062_auto_20170910_0953.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:53 0063_auto_20170910_0953.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:53 0064_auto_20170910_0953.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:53 0065_auto_20170910_0953.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:53 0066_auto_20170910_0953.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:53 0067_auto_20170910_0953.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:53 0068_auto_20170910_0953.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:54 0069_auto_20170910_0954.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:54 0070_auto_20170910_0954.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:54 0071_auto_20170910_0954.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:55 0072_auto_20170910_0955.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:56 0073_auto_20170910_0956.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:57 0074_auto_20170910_0957.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 12:59 0075_auto_20170910_0959.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:00 0076_auto_20170910_1000.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:01 0077_auto_20170910_1001.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:02 0078_auto_20170910_1002.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:03 0079_auto_20170910_1003.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:04 0080_auto_20170910_1004.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:05 0081_auto_20170910_1005.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:06 0082_auto_20170910_1006.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:07 0083_auto_20170910_1007.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:08 0084_auto_20170910_1008.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:09 0085_auto_20170910_1009.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:10 0086_auto_20170910_1010.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:11 0087_auto_20170910_1011.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:12 0088_auto_20170910_1012.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:13 0089_auto_20170910_1013.py
-rw-r--r--   1 userx  admin    788 Sep 10 13:14 0090_auto_20170910_1014.py
```

Is my makemigrations command caught in a loop? I've even stopped the containers `(docker-compose -f local.yml stop & docker-compose -f local.yml down)` but as soon as I continue with development the migration files keep popping up.

**UPDATE**

So I realized that docker wasn't down and running `docker container ps` listed running containers. The `web app` was showing `CREATED: 25 hours ago        STATUS: Restarting (0) 43 seconds ago`. I've now shutdown the containers and the files are still there. There is something that I don't get.

I have `restart: always` in local.yml. Is that what is causing the creation of many migration files? And why not other files but only the migration files?

Comment: Try removing restart property and see if that helps?

Comment: @TarunLalwani That's actually what I did and it stopped the creation of migration files. Question is why? Am looking to get a better understanding of Docker's plumbing... Why would a restart policy autocreate migration files and no other files?

Comment: I believe your container is exiting with non zero exit code and docker is continuously restarting it, you may be executing migrate at the start of the container and that may be causing the issue. Just a guess